# Using $(this) when selecting a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a series of divs all of the same class with no IDs.  I want to change the background of the div when it is clicked.  I tested the function and it works fine.  But when I access the element as *this*, it is not working.  Question is how to get buttonpressed() to work only for the div clicked on?

HTML

```
<div id="navbar">
    <div class="navitem" onclick="buttonpressed()"><p>Membership</p></div>
    <div class="navitem" onclick="buttonpressed()"><p>Certification</p></div>
    <div class="navitem" onclick="buttonpressed()"><p>Foundation</p></div>
    <div class="navitem" onclick="buttonpressed()"><p>Seminars</p></div>
    <div class="navitem" onclick="buttonpressed()"><p>Councils</p></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function buttonpressed() {
    var bgString = "url('navbuttonpressed.png')";
    $(this).css('backgroundImage',bgString);
}
```

Comment: `this` is window. if you want it to be the element, you'll either have to use a different event binding strategy, or use .call to change the context of the function.

Comment: Why are you mixing javascript onlick on html elements and jquery?  I'd highly recommend reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS and Javascript](http://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

Comment: So, you have jQuery and using inline handlers... Any reason to do so? Why not `$('#navbar').on('click', '.navitem', buttonpressed);`?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using jQuery you can (and should) remove the inline event handling and just use:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.navitem').click(function(){
        var bgString = "url('navbuttonpressed.png')";
        $(this).css('backgroundImage',bgString);
    })
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/t0L7L6k7/)**

Comment: Just for my reference, is there any benefit in using `bgString` to hold the CSS value rather than simply inlining it `$(this).css('backgroundImage', 'url("navbuttonpressed.png")');`?

Comment: @War10ck - no, not really. If that value was used elsewhere then sure, but for a single use then no.

Comment: Cool, that's what I was thinking as well. I wasn't sure if there was some secret benefit that I didn't know about though. Thanks for the response +1

Answer (score 0):

When using HTML inline event handlers, `this` references your window. If you instead attach an event handler through JavaScript, it will work as expected:

```js
$(".navitem").on("click", function () {
  var bgString = "url('navbuttonpressed.png')";
  $(this).css('backgroundImage',bgString);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="navitem"><p>Membership</p></div>
  <div class="navitem"><p>Certification</p></div>
  <div class="navitem"><p>Foundation</p></div>
  <div class="navitem"><p>Seminars</p></div>
  <div class="navitem"><p>Councils</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get access to this if you change how you're catching the event:

```
$('.navitem').on('click', function() {
     var bgString = "url('navbuttonpressed.png')";
     $(this).css('backgroundImage',bgString);
})
```

HTML

```
<div id="navbar">
<div class="navitem" ><p>Membership</p></div>
<div class="navitem" ><p>Certification</p></div>
<div class="navitem" ><p>Foundation</p></div>
<div class="navitem"><p>Seminars</p></div>
<div class="navitem" ><p>Councils</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, one way to do this would be:

```
$('.navitem').click(function(){

var bgString = "url('navbuttonpressed.png')";
$(this).css('backgroundImage',bgString);

});
```

Check: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Also keep in mind, that the code above will bind this function to all elements with the css-class "navitem". In case you do not know, what this means you might check as well: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".navitem").click(function(){
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url(https://www.google.pt/images/nav_logo195.png)');
});
```

---

Demo:

http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/bdddGa

Answer (score 0):

If you happened to want a pure JS solution and if you want to keep your inline `onClick` listeners, you could do this..

### HTML

```
<div class="navitem" onclick="buttonpressed(this)"><p>Membership</p></div>
```

### JS

```
function buttonpressed(element) {
    var bgString = "url('navbuttonpressed.png')";
    element.style.backgroundImage = bgString;
}
```

The `this` keyword passes the element that called the function through to the method itself.

This works well - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5u2ouvb/2/)